Adding a JSON index to MYSQL may result in empty query results
After I added an index to the json field in the database, some of Django's queries stopped working, so I looked into the underlying SQL and found something strange.
You can reproduce the problem with the following SQL.
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `info` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

ALTER TABLE products ADD INDEX tag_group_idx ((
    CAST(info->>'$."Group"' as CHAR(32)) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
)) USING BTREE;

INSERT INTO products (status, info) VALUES('active', '{"Group": "G0001"}');


MySQL version: 8.0.29.
OS: Windows


Generated by Django
SQL:
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE status = 'active' AND
JSON_EXTRACT(info,'$."Group"') = JSON_EXTRACT('"G0001"', '$');

Result:
id|status|info|
--+------+----+


Using plain string
SQL:
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE status = 'active' AND
JSON_EXTRACT(info,'$."Group"') = 'G0001';

Result:
id|status|info              |
--+------+------------------+
1|active|{"Group": "G0001"}|


Remove redundant query conditions
SQL:
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(info,'$."Group"') = JSON_EXTRACT('"G0001"', '$');

Result:
id|status|info              |
--+------+------------------+
1|active|{"Group": "G0001"}|



As shown above, I tried three ways to query, but only the first one had empty results. I guess it was caused by the mismatch of the generated column types.
I found that after I deleted the index, the first worked fine.
ALTER TABLE products DROP INDEX tag_group_idx;
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE status = 'active' AND
JSON_EXTRACT(info,'$."Group"') = JSON_EXTRACT('"G0001"', '$');

Can anyone tell me the real reason for this result and how to avoid the index affecting the query results?
Thank you!

AFAIR there were a lot of bugs in multivalued indices implementation, and these problems were fixed approx. in v.8.0.35.

I agree with @Akina. This question reads more like a bug report. I would first check if there is any similar bug already reported for mysql and if it has already been fixed in an already released mysql version.

Indexes should only affect performance. If you get different results because of an index, it's almost certainly a bug.
